# How to use a mongoTemplate with a qualifier in a MongoRepository?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

We have an in house configuration mechanism which create spring bean outside of the regular xml file or java Configuration class.

Inside this configuration, we have a mongoTemplate bean which is created with a specific qualifier "appMongoTemplate"

We can @autowired this mongoTemplate in our services like any regular spring bean:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("appMongoTemplate")
protected MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

Now I am trying to use a MongoRepository.
I just declare a regular interface:

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<MyDocument, String>
```

But when my application start, I have an exception during the repository creation, because it cannot find the mongoTemplate bean.
I guess I need to specify the name of the mongoTemplate to use, but I don't know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the XML namespace and the `@EnableMongoRepositories` annotation have an attribute to explicitly wire the `MongoTemplate` bean to be used for the repositories:

```
<mongo:repositories mongo-template-ref="appMongoTemplate" />
```

or

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(mongoTemplateRef = "appMongoTemplate")
```